# Xcode 7.2 upload tvos app with error: iTunes Store operation failed error can not verify client

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes, tvos, tvos9.1

I am trying to upload production build to iTunes Connect but getting error "iTunes Store operation failed error can not verify client".
[image]

How to fix it.

Comment: did you download Xcode from the OS X App Store ?

Comment: Yes , I have updated my Xcode from App Store.

Comment: Validate your Xcode as described here: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09222015a

Comment: But I have already uploaded iOS application build to iTunes Connect successfully recently but not got any error.

Comment: I have the same issue only for tvOS apps in XCode. Application Loader is working fine.

Comment: Application Loader also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, tried uploading the archive lots of times.

Then, I validated Xcode following the directions here:

http://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09222015a

Then restarted Xcode, rebuilt the archive and this time it worked.